# Loading virtual vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ogr

Can QGIS read layers in OGR's virtual *vector* format? It seems to work with VRT raster files, but it reports my layer is an invalid data source for vectors.

http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html

I'm running QGIS 2.6 on Windows with GDAL 1.11.0 (which supports virtual vectors).

I've created a virtual layer as follows, which concatenates 4 shapefile layers.

The reason for wanting to do this is that the data is too big to fit into a single shapefile. I could use another format, but it would be more convenient if I could just use a virtual raster. I'm sure there a plenty of valid reasons for wanting to do this.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="unionLayer">
        <OGRVRTLayer name="OSMM_SPNE">
            <SrcDataSource>OSMM_SPNE.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="OSMM_SPNW">
            <SrcDataSource>OSMM_SPNW.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="OSMM_SPSE">
            <SrcDataSource>OSMM_SPSE.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="OSMM_SPSW">
            <SrcDataSource>OSMM_SPSW.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
    </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

The `ogrinfo` tool can read the layer correctly:

```
$ ogrinfo -al -so virtual.xml
INFO: Open of `virtual.xml'
      using driver `VRT' successful.

Layer name: unionLayer
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1469256
Extent: (398123.820000, 196969.360000) - (501938.600000, 260658.500000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["British National Grid",
    GEOGCS["Ordnance Survey Great Brit",
        DATUM["Ordnance Survey Great Brit",
            SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996012717],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
TOID: String (20.0)
FEATCODE: Integer (9.0)
VERSION: Integer (9.0)
VERDATE: Date (10.0)
THEME: String (80.0)
CALCAREA: Real (19.11)
CHANGE: String (80.0)
DESCGROUP: String (150.0)
DESCTERM: String (150.0)
MAKE: String (20.0)
PHYSLEVEL: Integer (9.0)
PHYSPRES: String (20.0)
BROKEN: Integer (4.0)
LOADDATE: Date (10.0)
AREA: Real (19.11)
LEN: Real (19.11)
SYMBOLCODE: Integer (4.0)
SHAPE_Leng: Real (19.11)
SHAPE_Area: Real (19.11)
```

Comment: The probable answer to this question was given here http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2014-October/035289.html

Comment: Any progress with this ? I have looked at the link and created a VRT file but QGIS doesn't add any features.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to either add `relativeToVRT="1"` to the `SrcDataSource` element as it defaults to an absolute path or use an absolute path to the vector files.

From the VRT driver page:

> The element may optionally have a relativeToVRT attribute which defaults to "0"

Assuming `virtual.xml` is in `/tmp/test` (or `C:\Temp\test` if running on Windows). When you're running `ogrinfo` from the command line, your VRT will work *if* you're running the command from the same directory as the VRT (the `test` sub directory) - `ogrinfo virtual.xml`.  This is because `OSMM_SPNE.shp` is a relative path (i.e relative to the current directory).

If you ran `ogrinfo test/virtual.xml` from `/tmp` the command would fail as `ogrinfo` will look for OSMM_SP*.shp in `/tmp` and those shapefiles are not there, they're in `/tmp/test`.  When you're using QGIS, the current/working directory is unlikely be the directory your VRT and vector files are in, so QGIS (OGR) doesn't know where to find them.

The following VRT works in QGIS:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="unionLayer">
        <OGRVRTLayer name="test1">
            <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">test1.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="test2">
            <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">test2.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
    </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

So does this:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="unionLayer">
        <OGRVRTLayer name="test1">
            <SrcDataSource>/tmp/test/test1.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="test2">
            <SrcDataSource>/tmp/test/test2.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
    </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```