# Read >1 geometry fields into QGIS via ODBC from non-spatial database

Tags: qgis, odbc

I have a non-spatial database in FileMaker Pro that has two geometry fields per record (line and point).  The database has a geometry_columns table and using the method outlined by @MerseyViking at [Can QGIS read an ODBC connection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462), I can create a live link between one of the geometry fields and QGIS.

Is there any way to get QGIS to read >1 geometry field per record via ODBC?  I want to create one layer in QGIS for each geometry field in the database, but as the geometry_columns table is static (i.e. the f_geometry_column value can't be set or chosen from QGIS), this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Have you explored the OGR VRT driver? You can define geometry columns of wkt, wkb, etc. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120774/loading-virtual-vector-layer-in-qgis