# Creating virtual raster as layer to map with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, create, virtual-raster

I would like to load a virtual raster as a layer into my map. I have tried changing the data source attribute to 1 (relative), as described here:
[Loading virtual vector layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120774/loading-virtual-vector-layer-in-qgis)

What do I need to change for the raster? I have tried both `QgsRasterLayer` and `QgsVectorLayer`.

```py
import os
from osgeo import gdal

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='nearestNeighbor', addAlpha=False)
gdal.BuildVRT(r'D:\QGIS\ni25.vrt', [r'D:\QGIS\dtk25.tif'], options=vrt_options)

vrt_path = r'D:\QGIS\ni25.vrt'
Layer = QgsRasterLayer(vrt_path, "ni25_vrt", "ogr")

if not Layer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(Layer)
```

The layer is added but nothing shows up on the map and there is a warning saying that the layer data source could not be found. When I drag the vrt into the layers window, it works.

Comment: Try passing 'gdal' instead of 'ogr' for the provider argument. 'ogr' is for vector layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course *"Explicit is better than implicit"* as stated in [The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).

However, QGIS is smart and one can also create a `QgsRasterLayer` without specifying the `providerType`, e.g.:

```py
my_raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer("/path/to/file.tif", "my layer")
```

In your case it will be:

```py
Layer = QgsRasterLayer(vrt_path, "ni25_vrt")
```

See [QGIS Python API | Class: QgsRasterLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterLayer.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

As @BenW has pointed out, `ogr` has to be changed to `gdal`:

```py
Layer = QgsRasterLayer(vrt_path, "ni25_vrt", "gdal")
```